# NoSuchMethodError: java.lang.Exception.addSuppressed : Updating from Java 1.6 to 1.7

Tags: java, android, java-7

I started using Java 1.7 and I'm still using Eclipse. In my Project I add extra data to the thrown exception, with `handledException.addSuppressed(additionalException);` and it was working so far.

But according to my crash reports, some old OS installed devices(Android 2.3.4) are crashing with StackTrace below. But it doesn't occur in my Nexus 5 which has Android 4.4.4.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.lang.Exception.addSuppressed
```

I'm not really sure if there is some additional steps needed to update it to Java 1.7.

Comment: Older versions of Android are probably compiled with java 1.6. I would avoid using that method if it's causing problems for a significant number of your users.

Comment: It seems like I didn't check the API Level of that method. It has nothing to with Java 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

handledException.addSuppressed was added only in API 19.
You should put if else loop surrounding this piece of code

Comment: Thanks, I must have missed that out.

Answer (score 1):

Android 2.3 uses level 10 API. 
[`addSupressed()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Throwable.html#addSuppressed(java.lang.Throwable)) was added in level 19. In the future, check what API level was being used during that time (2.3), then check the API to see if it was available during that API level

Comment: Thanks, I must have missed that out.